# GTK RadioMenuItem is not firing group-changed signal

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3

I am working with GTK 3.24, Glade 3.38.2 and C++, where I have a signal handler function to deal with a GtkRadioMenuItem in a dropdown menu... however the event `group-changed` never get fired... the only way anything gets fired was to listen on `toggled` (fired only on the wrong/deselected item). I also tried `select` (doesn't get fired, but would hang if I am debugging).

I tried searching on Google and SO on `group-changed`, `RadioMenuItem` and even asked ChatGPT (lol) and came up with no information...

Could someone point me to the right direction on how to hook on the `group-changed` event?

[image]